# Why does writing to a bitfield-uint union by reference yield wrong assembly instruction?

Tags: c, arm, driver, unions, bit-fields

**First, some background:**

This issue popped up while writing a driver for a sensor in my embedded system (STM32 ARM Cortex-M4).

Compiler: `ARM NONE EABI GCC 7.2.1`

The best solution to representing the sensor's internal control register was to use a union with a bitfield, along these lines

```
enum FlagA {
   kFlagA_OFF,
   kFlagA_ON,
};

enum FlagB {
   kFlagB_OFF,
   kFlagB_ON,
};

enum OptsA {
   kOptsA_A,
   kOptsA_B,
   .
   .
   .
   kOptsA_G  // = 7
};

union ControlReg {
    struct {
        uint16_t  RESERVED1 : 1;
        FlagA     flag_a    : 1;
        uint16_t  RESERVED2 : 7;
        OptsA     opts_a    : 3;
        FlagB     flag_b    : 1;
        uint16_t  RESERVED3 : 3;
    } u;
    uint16_t reg;
};
```

This allows me to address the register's bits individually (e.g. `ctrl_reg.u.flag_a = kFlagA_OFF;`), and it allows me to set the value of the whole register at once (e.g. `ctrl_reg.reg = 0xbeef;`).

**The problem:**

When attempting to populate the register with a value fetched from the sensor through a function call, passing the union in by pointer, and then update only the `opts_a` portion of the register before writing it back to the sensor (as shown below), the compiler generates an incorrect `bitfield insert` assembly instruction.

```
ControlReg ctrl_reg;
readRegister(&ctrl_reg.reg);

ctrl_reg.opts_a = kOptsA_B;  // <-- line of interest

writeRegister(ctrl_reg.reg);
```

yields

```
ldrb.w r3, [sp, #13]
bfi r3, r8, #1, #3   ;incorrectly writes to bits 1, 2, 3
strb.w r3, [sp, #13]
```

However, when I use an intermediate variable:

```
uint16_t reg_val = 0;
readRegister(&reg_val);

ControlReg ctrl_reg;
ctrl_reg.reg = reg_val;
ctrl_reg.opts_a = kOptsA_B;  // <-- line of interest

writeRegister(ctrl_reg.reg);
```

It yields the correct instruction:

```
bfi r7, r8, #9, #3   ;sets the proper bits 9, 10, 11
```

The readRegister function does nothing funky and simply writes to the memory at the pointer

```
void readRegister(uint16_t* out) {
   uint8_t data_in[3];
   ...
   *out = (data_in[0] << 8) | data_in[1];
}
```

Why does the compiler improperly set the starting bit of the bitfield insert instruction?

Comment: Are you using gcc? Did you try `-fno-strict-aliasing`?

Comment: Matteo, yes, I'm using arm-none-eabi-gcc 7.2.1.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is wrong?  I mean, I suppose you're looking into the question because the observed behavior differs, but from the assembly code alone, it depends on whether the contents of `r8` are equivalent in the two cases, and on how the contents of `r3` are subsequently used.

Comment: @JohnBollinger You're right that I'm also looking at the result of the instructions, and whenever the questionable instruction is present, the phenotype is improper. Though, you make a great point: bits 9, 10, 11 ARE bits 1, 2, 3 of the 2nd byte of the bitfiled container. But what would lead the compiler to place only the top byte of the structure into `r8`? Perhaps I'm not following the rest of the disassembly fully, but without the intermediate variable the apparent behavior is wrong in the end. Hmm

Comment: Hmm.  The code you present does not go with the declaration of type `ControlReg` that you present.  When you say `ctrl_reg.opts_a`, do you mean `ctrl_reg.u.opts_a`?  Alternatively, is the structure member of `ControlReg` supposed to be anonymous?

Comment: the compiler is 100% fine. The generated code is OK

Comment: while gcc will allow code like that to work, thus far...you are deep into "implementation defined"  using bitfields in general, and misusing unions should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: +1 for looking at the compiler output.  Maybe this is a hint as to why the path you choose may not be right.  While it is possible to get this to work, it is very brittle.  Your bus (and r/w patterns) may change to SPI, I2C, etc, SOC module may update with bit changes, you may need to port or simulate the code on another CPU, your API to higher levels may need translation, etc.  Many people use RAM to shadow the registers as often these registers are very slow (wait states) compared to core memory.  An inline function and/or macros will give you much more control to adapt to these changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a fan of bitfields, especially if you're aiming for portability.  C leaves a lot more unspecified or implementation-defined about them than most people seem to appreciate, and there are some very common misconceptions about what the standard requires of them as opposed to what happens to be the behavior of some implementations.  Nevertheless, that's mostly moot if you're writing code for a specific application only, targeting a single, specific C implementation for the target platform.

In any case, C allows no room for a conforming implementation to behave inconsistently for conforming code.  In your case, it is equally valid to set `ctrl_reg.reg` through a pointer, in function `readRegister()`, as to set it via assignment.  Having done so, it is valid to assign to `ctrl_reg.u.opts_a`, and the result should read back correctly from `ctrl_reg.u`.  It is also permitted to afterward read `ctrl_reg.reg`, and that will reflect the result of the modification.

*However*, you are making assumptions about the layout of the bitfields that are not supported by the standard.  Your compiler will be consistent, but you need to carefully verify that the layout is actually what you expect, else going back and forth between the two union members will not produce the result you want.

Nevertheless, the way you store a value in `ctrl_reg.reg` is immaterial with respect to the effect that assigning to the bitfield has.  Your compiler is not required to generate identical assembly for the two cases, but if there are no other differences between the two programs and they exercise no undefined behavior, then they *are* required to produce the same observable behavior for the same inputs.

Comment: `I am not a fan of bitfields, especially if you're aiming for portability.` uC programmers use bitfields a lot. The whole AVR xMega or PIC vendor supplied headers are bitfield related. The portability is not something the uC programmers care too much about. They will use the same compiler all over again. And the uC code will not run on any other architecture. uC compiler port developers know it very well and they keep it  consistent and well defined. uC programming is different than portable unix machines coding

Comment: @P__J__ Until you want to run unit test on the code on the host or management wants to change CPUs or port it to a cell phone.  It is prudent to put non-portable code in a central place and wrap it so it is at least easy to find via grep, etc.  I find macros and bit defines just as readable and much more portable.  bitfields seems useful for data structures but not hardware mappings in my opinion.

Comment: @artlessnoise you did not catch. I was citing `John Bollinger` and arguing.  `but not hardware mappings in my opinion` never touch PIC or XMEGA uC. All hardware is bitfield mapped (you may of course write your own headers with all the definitions, types etc if you have weeks to spend)

Comment: @P__J__  while bitfields are used a lot it is implementation defined.  Its just a very bad habit that gains nothing, when you move into other compilers you will get bit hard with such a habit.  Takes seconds to write compliant code not weeks.

Comment: The big problem here is that using a bit-field for memory-mapped IO masks the underlying read and write operations that must take place.  With memory mapped IO one should care a lot about the order, number of them as they have side-effects.   Simply declaring the variable as `volatile` and hoping the compiler disables all optimisations that might come into play is a dangerous game In fact, `volatile` is the solution for almost no problem in low-level device programming.

Comment: Also the process to change from bit fields to defines is not a loss.  In many cases, the vendor bit fields have errors in them.  Even it they do not, a developer needs to read and understand what these bits do to properly code a driver.  Also, these values have a way of leaking to higher layer APIs unless you code a translation layer which may waste CPU time.  I agree with old_timer that it doesn't take that long, especially if you use a macro editor.

Comment: @marko ```volatile``` is required for shared variables among ISRs and the main thread.  ```volatile``` is also required for reads/writes to MMIO and hardware-modified registers (e.g. timers, SPI data register).  I wouldn't call that "almost no problem(s)"

Answer (score -1):

It is 100% correct compiler generated code

[image]

```
void foo(ControlReg *reg)
{
    reg -> opts_a = kOptsA_B;
}

void foo1(ControlReg *reg)
{
    volatile ControlReg reg1;

    reg1.opts_a = kOptsA_B;
}
```

---

```
foo:
        movs    r2, #1
        ldrb    r3, [r0, #1]    @ zero_extendqisi2
        bfi     r3, r2, #1, #3
        strb    r3, [r0, #1]
        bx      lr
foo1:
        movs    r2, #1
        sub     sp, sp, #8
        ldrh    r3, [sp, #4]
        bfi     r3, r2, #9, #3
        strh    r3, [sp, #4]    @ movhi
        add     sp, sp, #8
        bx      lr
```

As you see in the function 'foo' it loads only one byte (the second byte of the union) and the field is stored in 1 to 3 bits of this byte.

As you see in the function 'foo1' it loads half word (the whole structure) and the field is stored in 9 to 11 bits of the halfword.

Do not try to find errors in the compilers because they are almost always in your code.

## PS

You do not need to name struct and the padding bitfields

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint16_t : 1;
        uint16_t flag_a    : 1;
        uint16_t : 7;
        uint16_t opts_a    : 3;
        uint16_t flag_b    : 1;
        uint16_t : 3;
    };
    uint16_t reg;
}ControlReg ;
```

## EDIT

but if you want to make sure that the whole structure (union) is modified just make the function parameter `volatile`

```
void foo(volatile ControlReg *reg)
{
    reg -> opts_a = kOptsA_B;
}

foo:
        movs    r2, #1
        ldrh    r3, [r0]
        bfi     r3, r2, #9, #3
        strh    r3, [r0]        @ movhi
        bx      lr
```

Comment: So your conclusion is that the OP's observed difference in behavior arises from what? Something not presented in the question?

Comment: @JohnBollinger From the code we do not see. Compilers are right (in 99.99999999999999999999999999999999999999%), programmers are usually not, but (especially the not very ecxperienced) they like to blame the compiler

Comment: I agree that programs are wrong far, far more often than are compilers, but I do not find your specific example especially illuminating.  Note that in the OP's code, the two mismatched assembly results are attributed to identical direct assignments, whereas one of your assignments is indirect.

Comment: @JohnBollingerNo. The code shown by the OP `ldrb.w r3, [sp, #13]
bfi r3, r8, #1, #3` it reads odd (the second) byte of the union. Objects in the memory are even aligned. My example was a bit "forced" (trivial examples are substituted by simple store) to show the behavior. BTW are you ARM uCs specialist (do you actually program them on the daily basis)?

Comment: Yes.  The OP may be misrepresenting the actual situation, but what he *says* is that the same C statement, `ctrl_reg.opts_a = kOptsA_B;`, is compiled differently in his two variants of the program.

Comment: Thanks @P__J__ . Not trying *to blame* the compiler per se, was just more curious as to why it would yield such different bit assignments as I did not at first notice the correlation that John Bollinger pointed out with regards to the different parts of the union being stored in the register.

Comment: @JohnBollinger if he shown the the two lines before that bfi in the second example the mistery would be solved instantly

Comment: interesting - what is wrong in my answer to be DV-ted

Comment: isn't the problem here that this is a register that is memory mapped - so `foo()` which is generating byte-wide writes is unlikely to end well.  The compiler is at liberty to access it however it wants - the mistake is here is to let it by not controlling how the read takes place.  This is often a place where operating system provide a wrapper functions to do the write - usually with appropriate barrier instructions as well.

Comment: @marko no it is not. Hardware registers are always in C volatile. It prevents the byte access ass you see in one of my examples.

Comment: I just took a look at the draft C11 standard - nothing very apparent there requires a complier to do this.  I remember being surprised many years ago when developing for VxWorks that the functions it provided for performing memory mapped IO (all one-liners) lacked `volatile` - and this was why.  This seems to be non-portable code.  As other answers imply, unions of this type are not a great idea, and it's always better to do an explicit read-modify-write with a pointer-type correctly sized for the register.   If it's a write-only register you clearly need a copy of the last value written.

Comment: @marko stop this deeply theoretical deliberations. This topic is about ARM cortex implementations and the "Death C Machine" considerations are irrelevant. ARM cortex code which accesses the hardware registers is by definition not portable. But for uC programmers is more important that `*(volatile uint8_t * ...) = ..` will force the compiler to use the 8bit access, not 16 or 32, than the portability, as it has serious consequences. If you want an example - STM32 SPI data register (if the uC has implemented FIFO). 16 bit access will add two values to the FIFO instead of one

Comment: Unions asd bitfields are perfectly good for this kind of programming work. They are not same good if you write portable Linux program.